# Hands on knees as if panting

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Term for one's hands on knees, torso and head bent over as if ones exhausted?

Comment: Why not 'exhausted'? Please provide the sentence where you'll use this.

Comment: It's getting towards the 'foetal position'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about **winded**? From Cambridge:

> **[winded](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/winded)**: having difficulty breathing, usually because you have just done some physical activity that caused you to breathe too quickly

This captures your references to *panting* and *exhausted*. It doesn't necessarily result in the pose you describe -- "hands on knees, torso and head bent over" -- but it usually does.